# Sql conditional count

Tags: sql, sqlite

Can anyone help me with the sql and sqlite query for the below condition. To be specific, i wanted to show the merged count of 2 categories.

```
**Table**
Category    Sub_category
  A              1
  A              2
  A              2
  B              1
  C              1
  C              1
  C              2
  D              1
  D              1
  D              1
  D              2
  D              3
**Required Output**
    Category    Sub_category    Count   **condition(not part of o/p just instruction)**
        A             1           1        -
        A             2+          2        -    
        B             1           1        -    
        C             1           2        -
        C             2+          1        -
        D             1           3        -    
        D             2+          1 should contain the count of 2 and more
```

i am able to achieve the same using below:

```
  select Category,
         count(CASE WHEN Sub_category = 1 THEN Sub_category END) AS '1',
         count(CASE WHEN Sub_category >= 2 THEN Sub_category END) AS '2+'
  from table
```

however output is little different hence looking for the first output only.

```
**Output**
Category    1   2+
   A        1   2
   B        1   0
   C        1   2
   D        3   2
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `Sub_category >= 2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want:

```
select Category,
       (case when sub_category = 1 then '1' else '2+' end) as sub_category,
       count(*)
from table
group by Category,
         (case when sub_category = 1 then '1' else '2+' end);
```

That is, you want to put the sub category groups on *rows*, not as columns.

Answer (score 1):

You are just missing one column. Add the last count without a filtering to get the total:

```
select Category,
     count(CASE WHEN Sub_category = 1 THEN Sub_category END) AS '1',
     count(CASE WHEN Sub_category >= 2 THEN Sub_category END) AS '2+',
     count(*)
   from table
   group by Category, count(CASE WHEN Sub_category = 1 THEN Sub_category END), count(CASE WHEN Sub_category >= 2 THEN Sub_category END), count(*)
```

Comment: Thanks, you are Awesome!